# Inserting new row on datagrid view and getting error

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, datagrid, datagridview, wpfdatagrid

I have a datagrid view on windows form application, and I'm trying to insert data from excel. I'm using a function to "paste" the data to the grid, but when I have to add new row, I get error.

> `Index was out of range. It must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.  Parameter name: index`

My datagrid is based on datasource by a query by linq to SQL. I don't know what I have to do, to allow to create a new line.

this is my code:

```
if (DadosClientes.Rows.Count < (r + rowsInClipboard.Length))
{

}
for (int iRow = 0; iRow < rowsInClipboard.Length; iRow++)
{
    string[] valuesInRow = rowsInClipboard[iRow].Split(columnSplitter);

    DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)DadosClientes.Rows[0].Clone();

    for (int iCol = 0; iCol < valuesInRow.Length; iCol++)
    {
        if (DadosClientes.ColumnCount - 1 >= c + iCol)
        {
            DadosClientes.Rows[r + iRow].Cells[c + iCol].Value = valuesInRow[iCol];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, there is an empty `if` statement in your code. Is that supposed to be wrapped around your outer `for` loop?

Comment: I try to do this:   DadosClientes.Rows.Add(r + rowsInClipboard.Length - DadosClientes.Rows.Count) but I get error